# how to implement Undo feature in drawing so that user can clear his last line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am using CoreGraphics to implement free hand drawing which is working fine for me and now I want to implement Undo feature for this drawing so that user can clear his last strok

Answer (score 5):

In your method:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(imageView2.image != nil){
        [pathArray addObject:imageView2.image];
    }

}
```

And on undo button:

```
if([pathArray count]>0)
{
    [pathArray removeLastObject];
    if([pathArray count]==0)
    {
        imageView2.image = GlobalImage2;
    }
    else
    {
        imageView2.image=[pathArray objectAtIndex:[pathArray count]-1];
    }

}
```

Retrive this image from array.
I have used same code in my few apps. I hope it'll be useful for you.

Thanks,

Hemang.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about the Memento Pattern. Some links:

- http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-memento

In time, sorry for not explaining it here. But there are tons of books and articles about it.

Answer (score 0):

I never used this but you can find over here to undo or clear last things

[http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/acedrawingview?utm_source=Cocoa+Controls&utm_campaign=eaef7635b9-Cocoa_Controls_Weekly_Roundup_2013_01_1%27&utm_medium=email](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/acedrawingview?utm_source=Cocoa%20Controls&utm_campaign=eaef7635b9-Cocoa_Controls_Weekly_Roundup_2013_01_1%27&utm_medium=email)